# class_exists returns different values

Tags: php, plugin-development

In my Plugin classes I want to check if the classes are existing (maybe by another plugin)
I'm doing it the following way:

```
/**
* @author schmitt
*
* @file my_util_class.php
*
* @class my_util_class
*
* @brief small message
*
* big message
*/
if ( ! class_exists( 'my_util_class' ) ) :

class my_util_class
{
   /**
    * @brief smalltest
    * bigtestmessage
    */
  public function test() {
       return "hallo";
   }

   //definition of other methods.
}

endif;
```

until now it works fine. But I want to use doxygen and there I have problems, because doxygen doesn't see the classes inside the if / endif construct.

So I tried the following:

```
if (class_exists('my_util_class')) {
    return;
}
class my_util_class {
    //...
}
```

But in this case, "class_exists" everytime gives "true".

I checked the values and get the following:

```
/*
 * Test 1
 */
$testValue = class_exists('my_util_class'));; //gets true
class my_util_class {
    //...
}

/*
 * Test 2
 */
$testValue = class_exists('my_util_class')); //gets false
if ( ! class_exists( 'my_util_class' ) ) :
    class my_util_class {
        //...
    }
}
```

I don't understand why. Hope somebody can help me, or give me a better way to test if the class exist?

Comment: watch out of the fonction name, it's `class_exists` with a "s" at end

Comment: sorry, my bad. It was a copy / paste  failure by writing this question. In my plugin I have it right, so the problem still exists.

Comment: I highly recommend you to keep these things separate. One file should only include the class itself, nothing else. Then, in the file that actually uses the class, you can call `class_exists()` and load the class when necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In PHP the files are parsed before they are executed, so function and class definitions are 'hoisted' so that they are defined at the beginning of execution, regardless of where they are defined. This *doesn't* happen when they are conditionally defined, as conditions aren't evaluated until execution.

This, from the PHP manual, was all I could find in terms of documentation of this (but I'm probably searching for the wrong thing, 'hoisting' is a JS term):

> Functions need not be defined before they are referenced, *except* when
>   a function is conditionally defined as shown in the two examples
>   below.
>
> When a function is defined in a conditional manner such as the two
>   examples shown. Its definition must be processed prior to being
>   called.

http://php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php

EDIT: Another explanation, from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21437344/2684861).

> Conditionally declared classes must come first. Basically, anything
>   that's at the "top level" of the file is handled directly by the
>   parser while parsing the file, which is the step before the runtime
>   environment executes the code (including `new Foo`). However, if a class
>   declaration is nested inside a statement like `if`, this needs to be
>   evaluated by the runtime environment. Even if that statement is
>   guaranteed to be true, the parser cannot evaluate `if (true)`, so the
>   actual declaration of the class is deferred until runtime. And at
>   runtime, if you try to run `new Foo` before `class Foo { }`, it will fail.

Comment: Thank You! I didn't know, that the class and function definitions are getting defined at the beginning, except when they are in a conditional clause. Now I understand what happens!